# Share query in TFS between teams

Tags: tfs, alm, tfs-2015

I have a TFS project with multiple teams, where each team is actually a separate project - we're going the [one team project to rule them all](http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project/) way...

But I'd like to share a lot of queries between these teams, so that if I'm on the web site for "Project / Team A" looking at the Bug-list, I only see the bugs for this team... and vice versa if I'm looking at the Bug-list for "Project / Team B".

A basic query could look like this:

```
Team Project = @Project
And Work Item Type = Bug
And State <> Removed
```

But then I see all bugs for all teams, no matter what team I have selected on the web site.

If I change the query to the following, it kind of works

```
Team Project = @Project
And Iteration Path = @CurrentIteration   <-- Notice this line ;-)
And Work Item Type = Bug
And State <> Removed
```

This only gives me the bugs inside the current iteration, but now the query is team dependent, so I only see the bugs for the team, which web site I'm on.

Is there any way to fix this? Except for creating queries for each them setting the Iteration Path to "Under xxx"?

Comment: Good job on the one team project, you won't regret it! Please update here if you ever find a workaround as this is something I would like to implement too. We are currently using the same as in Eddies answer

Comment: All you can do is create a query for each team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this.

The thing you can do is create separate queries for different teams and specify the team area path in these queries via:

```
And Area Path = "Team Area Path".
```

Comment: Correct, there is no way to do this. You should add it on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com